# How to highlight entire row when the checkbox is selected

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jsf-2

I have a JSF datatable. I want to highlight the row when I select the the corresponding check box . How I must edit the JavaScript code to achieve this effect?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <ui:insert name="header">           
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>         
        </ui:insert>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h1><img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="NVIDIA.com" /> History Center</h1>
        <!-- layer for black background of the buttons -->
        <div id="toolbar" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1180px; height:30px; position:relative;  background-color:black">
            <!-- Include page Navigation -->
            <ui:insert name="Navigation">           
                <ui:include src="Navigation.xhtml"/>         
            </ui:insert>

        </div>  

        <div id="greenBand" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-allh" style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;"> 
            <h:graphicImage alt="Dashboard"  style="position:relative; top:-20px; left:9px;"  value="resources/images/logo_sessions.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:700px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:105px">

            <div id="mainpage" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:80px">

                <div id="settingsHashMap" style="width:750px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">

                    <h:form id="form">

                        <!-- The sortable data table -->
                        <h:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{SessionsController.dataList}" var="item">

                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Account Session ID" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Account Session ID" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.aSessionID}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="User ID" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="User ID" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.userID}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity Start Time" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity Start Time" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activityStart}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity End Time" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity End Time" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activityEnd}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activity}" />
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>

                        <!-- The paging buttons -->
                        <h:commandButton value="first" action="#{SessionsController.pageFirst}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow == 0}" />
                        <h:commandButton value="prev" action="#{SessionsController.pagePrevious}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow == 0}" />
                        <h:commandButton value="next" action="#{SessionsController.pageNext}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow + SessionsController.rowsPerPage >= SessionsController.totalRows}" />
                        <h:commandButton value="last" action="#{SessionsController.pageLast}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow + SessionsController.rowsPerPage >= SessionsController.totalRows}" />
                        <h:outputText value="Page #{SessionsController.currentPage} / #{SessionsController.totalPages}" />
                        <br />

                        <!-- The paging links -->
                        <ui:repeat value="#{SessionsController.pages}" var="page">
                            <h:commandLink value="#{page}" actionListener="#{SessionsController.page}"
                                           rendered="#{page != SessionsController.currentPage}" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{page}" escape="false"
                                          rendered="#{page == SessionsController.currentPage}" />
                        </ui:repeat>
                        <br />

                        <!-- Set rows per page -->
                        <h:outputLabel for="rowsPerPage" value="Rows per page" />
                        <h:inputText id="rowsPerPage" value="#{SessionsController.rowsPerPage}" size="3" maxlength="3" />
                        <h:commandButton value="Set" action="#{SessionsController.pageFirst}" />
                        <h:message for="rowsPerPage" errorStyle="color: red;" />

                    </h:form>                  

                </div>   

                <div id="settingsdivb" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:800px">

                </div>   
            </div>  
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
              $("tr").not(':first').hover(
              function () {
                $(this).css("background","#787878");
              }, 
              function () {
                $(this).css("background","");
              }
            );
        </script>


    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post a snippet of the output from "View Source" of your generated page?  Just what comes back for one of the rows (including the checkbox) would be fine.

Comment: This is the HTML source code: http://pastebin.com/XcQ4v2MP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well my approach with jQuery is this :

```
            <p:column >
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="highlight(this)" />
            </p:column>
```

Create `.highlighted` class in your CSS file:

```
.highlighted {
    background-color: red;
}
```

And finally actual function:

```
          function highlight(param) {  
            var row = jQuery(param).parent().parent(); //children() available as well
                row.toggleClass('highlighted');
          }
```

You just get the `row` of the clicked `checkbox` and handle assigning of the `CSS class`. Straight and simple.

**EDIT**: Of course number of `.parent()` depends on your html elements composition. Edited the function to fit on your case, I've tried it with different composition of elements.

Comment: That entire if statement would be avoided with [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: @Scott true fact, I will correct it asap. Thank you for pointing that out !

Comment: Your code works: http://pastebin.com/6MTewWdg  But there is a problem - when I click on a check box every row in the table is highlighted. The problem is that every row has the same id. How I can generate unique id for every row in JSF data table?

Comment: According to your composition, remove one .parent() from the script. The problem is not with ids, standard JSF 2.0 h:dataTable doesn't add ids to rows at all. Problem is that you are going 1 more level higher with .parent() as you should (in html element tree).

Comment: I saw one issue with the code. The h:datatable uses pagination. When I switch to the second page and then I return to the first page the selected row is lost(unchecked). The information about the selected pages is not remembered. How I the h:datatable can remember the selected rows when I swish to other page and return back?

Comment: That's completely new question. Make a new question so others can see it too.

Answer (score 6):

I can't really tell where your checkboxes are or what their names are but, I did notice you are using jQuery in your script.  I created a quick little ***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/xGaRv/)*** to show you what you can do with jQuery.  In my example, I created a `.highlight` class where I set the `background-color` to the color I want.  In jQuery, I group all of the checkboxes and attach a ***[`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)*** handler to them where I toggle the highlight class on/off every click.

***[Check out the jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/xGaRv/)***

### HTML:

```html
<div id="row-1"><input type="checkbox" id="chk-1" />Row 1</div>
<div id="row-2"><input type="checkbox" id="chk-2" />Row 2</div>
<div id="row-3"><input type="checkbox" id="chk-3" />Row 3</div>
<div id="row-4"><input type="checkbox" id="chk-4" />Row 4</div>
```

### CSS:

```css
div
{
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-bottom: dashed 1px #000;
}

input
{
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.highlight
{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

### jQuery:

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {

    var $chk = $(this),
        num = $chk.attr("id").substring(4),
        $row = $("#row-" + num);

    $row.toggleClass("highlight");

});
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that I can place div into JSF h:datatable?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of what I've done for getting Javascript to change background colors when checkboxes are checked:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr id="changeme1">
                <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="highlight('changeme1');" /></td>
                <td>Test Box</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="changeme2">
                <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="highlight('changeme2');" /></td>
                <td>Test2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script>
        function highlight(id)
        {
            object = document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor;
            if(object == "yellow")
            {
                document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "white";
            }else{
                document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            }
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried you proposal: http://pastebin.com/mC2yrj4a It's not working. Maybe there is a bug.